# React tailwind, cannot pass tailwind css from parent to child

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

I am running into a simple issue that doesn't seem to have an answer on quick google search or Tailwind doc.

I am a Vuejs user but I have started learning React. I have opted to use TailwindCSS for testing my React application but I noticed there is some differences of Tailwind usage between Vuejs and React.

In Vue, I can control a child component via the parent component like so:

```
Parent component:
<template>
 <div class="w-screen">
  <ChildComponent class="w-1/2 mx-auto" />
 </div>
</template>
```

With the child being able to centre on screen through the above parent component as should in the ChildComponent's class.

However, when I tried to do the same in React like so:

```
Parent component:
import Homepage from './views/Homepage';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className='bg-black w-screen'>
      <Homepage className="w-1/2 mx-auto"/>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Nothin happens when I placed the CSS at the Homepage child component from the parent.

I am sure there is a simple answer but I wasn't about to search the doc or use any keywords to find this problem. Anyone got a hint or confirm this is intended in React or have I done something wrong with the installation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is less of a Tailwind question and more of a React question. You cannot use `className` on the `Homepage` component without passing it as a prop. In your case, `Homepage` is not expecting any `className`. So while making your Homepage component you have to provide a prop called 'className' then it will work fine.
Or if you simply use a `div` in place of Homepage it will work normally. Have a look at this [codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/center-div-forked-l4ysy?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Thank you, adding a div makes more sense. Otherwise I would have to pass a prop at the child component every time I set something at the parent.

Answer (score 1):

You need to consider that `<Homepage/>` is a React component and cannot accept HTMLAttrs just like that.
this example might clear it:

```js
const app = () => {
    <div className="bg-black">
        <Homepage className="bg-red" />
    </div>
}
```

```js
const homePage = (props) => {
    <div className={props.className}>
        <h1 className="bg-red">hi</h1>
    </div>
}
```

the `className` that you pass to `<Homepage/>` is actually a props rather than Html attribure.

Answer (score 0):

In Vue it's fairly straightforward but in react you need to be explicit and use `className` in your component

```js
// Creating component
const Button = ({ className, children }) => {
  return <button className={`${className} bg-red-500`}>{children}</button>
}

export default Button
```

```js
// Using component
<Button className="text-white">MyButton</Button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import Homepage from './views/Homepage';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className='bg-black w-screen'>
      <Homepage className="w-1/2 mx-auto"/>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

views/Homepage
you have to receive props that are going to be passed as className

```
    const homePage = ({className}) => {
        <div className={className}>
            <h1 className="bg-red">hi</h1>
        </div>
    }
    export default homePage
```

then export your component